# Get an ACF custom field from an adjacent post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Wordpress plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

I'm viewing the single.php page for a custom post type. At the bottom of the page I'd like to show next and previous post links that show an accompanying image. This image value is an ACF custom field. How do I get and display the next/previous posts image with links?

Currently my broken code below shows the image of the page I'm already viewing:

```
<?php 

    $size = "medium";

    $prevPost = get_previous_post(true); 

    $prevThumbnail = get_field('bg_image', $prevPost->ID); 
    $bgimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $prevThumbnail, $size );

?>

    <img src="<?php echo $bgimage[0]; ?>" />
    <?php previous_post_link( '<strong>%link</strong>' ); ?>
```

**EDIT**

As per @d79's comment I've done a vardump of `$prevThumbnail` and all that is returned is the below, what does this mean?

```
int(1046)
```

**EDIT EDIT**

OK, so I've done a vardump on the custom field `bg_image` and I get the same number returned:

```
int(1046)
```

However, after turning on debugging in wp_config, I also get the following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bao-agency/wp-content/themes/bao/single-work.php on line 19
```

This refers to this line:

```
$prevThumbnail = get_field('bg_image', $prevPost->ID);
```

This `bg_image` field is an image field set as an Image ID not an array in Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: what does `get_field('bg_image', $prevPost->ID)` returns? the object, the url or the ID of the image field? I ask because you can change that on the field options

Comment: I'm not that great with PHP so how do I find out what is returned, do I need to print something on the page to see? Sorry...

Comment: `var_dump($prevThumbnail);`

Comment: @d79 See updated question with the result

Comment: it means that it returns the ID of the image (1046), and that's strange because it should work. try to do a `var_dump(get_field('bg_image'));` to see if it's really different

Comment: @d79 See updated question with the result. I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notice error means that `$prevPost` is not a post object, and that can happen if the global `$post` is not set or there is not a previous post in the same category, so `get_field('bg_image', $prevPost->ID)` fails and retrieve the image of the current post.

To avoid that you need to check if `$prevPost` is an object:

```
<?php 

    global $post;
    $prevPost = get_previous_post(true);

    if( is_object($prevPost) ):

        $prevThumbnail = get_field('bg_image', $prevPost->ID); 
        $bgimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $prevThumbnail, 'medium' );

?>

    <?php if($bgimage): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $bgimage[0]; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php previous_post_link( '<strong>%link</strong>', '%title', true ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Notice that I added also the third argument `true` to `previous_post_link` to retrieve the link of the previous post but in the same category.